# npm and sails lift trouble on windows

Tags: node.js, server, sails.js

Im trying to run `sails lift` in an existing project cloned from my github team repository, in the office everything is fine but in my home if I build a new sails using `sails new` run perfect but to run my existing project show errors:

### C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd>npm install

> sails@0.12.3 preinstall C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails
>   node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
npm WARN deprecated native-or-bluebird@1.1.2: 'native-or-bluebird' is deprecated. Please use 'any-promise' instead.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!

> typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\i18n\node_modules\messageformat\node_modules\watchr\node_modules\extendr\node_modules\typechecker
>   node ./cyclic.js
>
> typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\i18n\node_modules\messageformat\node_modules\watchr\node_modules\extract-opts\node_modules\typechecker
>   node ./cyclic.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json.4133996182
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json.4133996182' -> 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json.4133996182' -> 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json.4133996182',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\supports-color\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd>sails lift

info: Starting app...

debug: hookPath: C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-permissions\dist\api\hooks\permissions
debug: marlinspike (permissions): loading config from C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-permissions\dist\config
debug: marlinspike (permissions): loading Services from C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-permissions\dist\api\services...
debug: marlinspike (permissions): loading Models...
debug: marlinspike (permissions): loading Controllers...
debug: marlinspike (permissions): loading Policies...
warn: sails.getBaseUrl() is deprecated and will be removed in Sails v1.0.  See http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/sails-getbaseurl for more info.
warn: sails.getBaseUrl() is deprecated and will be removed in Sails v1.0.  See http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/sails-getbaseurl for more info.
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at afterwards (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:72:13)
    at C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:40:7
    at Handshake.onConnect (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:364:14)
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:421:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)

C:\Users\dev\Desktop\business\appBackEnd>

How can I start sails lift in an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm cache clean`

Source : `https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826`

### Friendly Advice

Also, don't post answers on SO which can be easily googled. First, spend a bit time googling around, and only post after you can;t find anything relevant.

I was able to find the above answer just by googling the first line at which the error occurred

`npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR`